# symbol argument for function input parameter

Tags: c#, arguments, symbols

I am writing a c# code and I want to pass an argument in a function, which will be one of theses symbols <, >, ==, !=

```
private Image ThresholdImageFilter(image, symbol, threshold)
{

for (int i = 1; i < 512; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j < 512; j++)
    {
       for (int j = 1; j < 512; j++)
         {
          if pixel symbol threshold;
               {
                     pixel = 1;
               }
          else
               {
                     pixel = 0;
               }
         }
    }
  }

}
```

I want to call many times a function,but with different symbols, like this:

```
AImage = ThresholdImageFilter(image > threshold);
BImage = ThresholdImageFilter(image < threshold);
CImage = ThresholdImageFilter(image <= threshold);
DImage = ThresholdImageFilter(image >= threshold);
```

I am searching for something like this:

```
private Image Filter(Bitmap image, symbolArgument symbol, int threshold)
{
     ...
}
```

and finally call the function like this:

```
BinaryImage = Filter(imageB, >, threshold);
```

Is there a way to do it? If so, please suggest how the >= or <= will be passed (which consist of 2 symbols).

Comment: What do you want to happen here?  It's really unclear.  Does `Filter` accept a `bool` or something else?

Comment: Are you trying to have your function accept an `Expression`?

Comment: Filter gets an image, compares the elements with a threshold, and then  outputs another image

Comment: The Filter is written

Answer (score 4):

Have filter accept a delegate that accepts two parameters and returns a boolean.  You can then pass a lambda to that argument using the given operator:

```
public SomeResult Filter(Func<ArgumentType, ArgumentType, bool> predicate)
{
    if(predicate(operand1, operand2))
        DoSomething();
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
var result = Filter((a,b)=> a > b);
```